# Regex- Ignore Alpha-Numeric except few specialcharacters

Tags: python, regex, unix, scripting

Trying to find if an input contains any non-aplanumeric characters with few exceptions. I am able to filter out the Non-aplanumeric characters but how do I add the exception cases?

1. Valid Input: `er(fsf@/=1$2)3\`
2. Invalid Input: `wer1ëį2342343`

Exception characters: `( ) \ / @ = $ *`

current regex: `re.search(r'\W-+', input)`:

Comment: Try `r'^[\w()@=\\/$*]*$'`. Note that the title is very confusing, alphanumerics do not contain special characters.

Comment: Any feeback? Please clarify *filter out*. What do you need to match? What do you want to avoid matching? See https://regex101.com/r/kR8mT5/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew basically I want to ignore any string that contains special characters besides the ones: ( , _ ) \ / @ ! < > # $ & *

Comment: What do you mean by *ignore*? Regexes either match a string or not. Try `re.search(r'[^\w(),_\\/@!<>#$&*]', input)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, My bad I am not explaining well. Basically "Find a string which has characters besides "( , _ ) \ / @ ! < > # $ & * – " and Alpha-Numeric.

Comment: But your valid input has a `@` as well.

Comment: So, could you provide any example strings that should match and that should not?